# How to use a get and post on same page using server request method

Tags: php

I am trying to use a get and post on same page using the server request method... i have another working method but i want to try a new method.
How do i retain the $_GET['email_address'] variable so i can use it in the POST method.

```
<?php $timestamp = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time()); ?>
<?php
$email_address = $str = "";
$email_address_error = $str_error = "";

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET"){

if(empty($_GET["email_address"])){
    $email_address_error = "<div class=''>email address is empty, please check your link.</div>";
}else{
    $email_address = test_input($_GET["email_address"]);
}

if(empty($_GET["str"])){
    $str_error = "<div class=''>email address is empty, please check your link.</div>";
}else{
    $str = test_input($_GET["str"]);
}   
}
```

i want the post method to grab the $_GET variable so i can pass it down to the next... Thats all i need.

```
$password = $confirm_password = "";
$password_error = $confirm_password_error = "";
$email_address = test_input($_GET["email_address"]);

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

if(empty($_POST["password"])){
    $password_error = "<div class=''>Password is required</div>";
}else{
    $password = test_input($_POST["password"]);
    //check if password is atleast 7 characters
    if(!preg_match("/^(?=.*?[a-z]).{7,}$/",$password)){
        $password_error = "<div class=''>Password must be atleast 7 characters</div>";
    }
}   

if(empty($_POST["confirm_password"])){
    $confirm_password_error  = "<div class=''>Alternate password is required</div>";
}else{
    $confirm_password = test_input($_POST["confirm_password"]);

    if(!preg_match("/^(?=.*?[a-z]).{7,}$/",$confirm_password)){
        $confirm_password_error = "<div class=''>Password must be atleast 7 characters</div>";
    }else{
        if($_POST['confirm_password'] != $password){
            $confirm_password_error = "<div class=''>Password does not match!!!</div>";
        }
    }
}

if($password_error == "" && $confirm_password_error == ""){
    $sql  = "UPDATE customer_registration SET password='$password', str='', updated_at='$timestamp' WHERE email_address='$email_address'";
        $database->query($sql);
        $mail = new Mail();
        $mail->email_address  =  $email_address;
        $mail->reset_password();    
        $session->message('<div class="btn bg-success">Congratulations!!! Your password has been updated. </div>');
    redirect_to('login.php');
}   

if(empty($_POST["message"])){
    $message = "";
}   else{
    $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
}   
}

function test_input($data){
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    $data = htmlentities($data);
    return $data;
}
?>
```

Comment: put that $_GET['email_address']  in hidden element , then post will have it

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: "i want the post method to grab the $_GET variable"  Can you show specifically what you mean by this?

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about this is to use the same, generic code regardless of whether the request was submitted as a GET or a POST.  (So you don't even need to test for the $_SERVER['Request_Method'].)

That's what the $_REQUEST superglobal is for.  From the documentation:

"An associative array that by default contains the contents of $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE." (https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)

When $_GET, $_POST, and/or $_COOKIE have elements with the same index, the **request_order** directive determines which one will be used to populate $_REQUEST. (https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.request-order.)

Of course, if you absolutely need to keep the $_GET superglobal in your code and you can't change to $_REQUEST, then another option would be to manually populate the $_GET superglobal from $_POST:

```
foreach($_POST as $index => $value){
  if(!isset($_GET[$index])){$_GET[$index] = $value;}
}
```